# How to avoid if / else if chain when classifying a heading into 8 directions?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 30 || this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() >= 330)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::RIGHT;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 30 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 60)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 60 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 120)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::UP;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 120 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 150)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::UP_LEFT;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 150 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 210)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::LEFT;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 210 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 240)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::DOWN_LEFT;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 240 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 300)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::DOWN;
else if (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() > 300 && this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() <= 330)
  this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT;
```

I want to avoid the `if`s chain; it's really ugly. Is there a another, possibly cleaner, way of writing this?

Comment: @Neil With a pair as you mentioned.

Comment: _@Oraekia_ It would look a lot less uglier, less to type and better to read if you fectch the `this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle()` once before the whole cascade.

Comment: All that explicit dereferencing of `this` (`this->`) is not needed and doesn't really do anything good to the readability..

Comment: @ πάντα  I don't see how that would work for a map - he is looking to see if the value is _between_ the  values in the pair.

Comment: @Neil Pair as key, enum as value, custom lookup lambda.

Comment: @πάντα  I'd be interested to see the lookup function. It would probably be _more_ complex than the OP's existing code.

Comment: The code would be a lot less ugly without all those `>` tests; they aren't needed, since each of them has already been tested (in the opposite direction) in the previous `if` statement.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's one of my pet peeves about code like this. Too many programmers don't understand `else if`.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? I agree that as a matter of opinion the if chain is ugly but is there some way that you can edit this question to more objectively qualify what would be better? Another alternative I can think of is instead of asking for a better way of writing this would be simply to ask for **other** ways of writing it.

Comment: Also, what's the use case for the *direction* value? I.e. how's `this->_car.edir` being used? Is embedding this data as a member variable that's just a cache of the `this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() / 30` wasteful of memory or does this cached value actually speed-up operations where speed is important or is there some other value for it?

Comment: What about using switch statements?

Comment: Most of the answers seem to be assuming that getAbsoluteAngle() returns an integer. If that's not true (if it's returning a real/float), then they'll likely need to be adjusted slightly/significantly. (@Oraekia, You may want to clarify the type in the question, as it may change things.)

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Ranges (even mutually exclusive ones) don't work well with hash tables, but with red-black trees they work just fine.  `std::map` is a red-black tree.  The `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` member functions (not the generic algorithms by the same name) will be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar it's not only a problem with `else if`, it's a really common problem with thresholds, too. An impressive number of people do not understand that a "slice" is self contained and ends before the next one start. So they do the double check **and** overlap the thresholds exactly like in this question. I even had a strong argument on this with some Wikipedia moderators, too, as there were tables like "1 to 10", "10 to 100", "100 to ..."

Comment: @Barmar It's usally not a matter of not understanding `else if` it's a matter of being absent minded or not very good at maths.

Comment: Are you aware of pattern matching in some languages? http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/functions.html maybe there's a way you can do this in your language.

Comment: if all those angles were sequential, then you could write a table with two items in each entry. 1) the max angle 2) the resultant direction,  Then you could just loop through that table, and return the direction for the entry the includes the current angle.  However, the very first entry includes everything from 30 degrees through 330 degrees, a 60 degree arc, BUT the checks are saying the resultant direction is RIGHT, when actually that arc is +- 30 degrees of due north, not right/east

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

enum Direction { UP, UP_RIGHT, RIGHT, DOWN_RIGHT, DOWN, DOWN_LEFT, LEFT, UP_LEFT };

Direction GetDirectionForAngle(int angle)
{
    const Direction slices[] = { RIGHT, UP_RIGHT, UP, UP, UP_LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, DOWN_LEFT, DOWN, DOWN, DOWN_RIGHT, RIGHT };
    return slices[(((angle % 360) + 360) % 360) / 30];
}

int main()
{
    // This is just a test case that covers all the possible directions
    for (int i = 15; i < 360; i += 30)
        std::cout << GetDirectionForAngle(i) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

This is how I would do it. (As per my previous comment).

Comment: If you're in control of the enum definition, you could arrange for the members to be in the order shown in `slices`, then it's just `return Dir((angle % 360) / 30);` (and the explicit conversion is needed only if you use `enum class`).

Comment: No, I'm wrong - I didn't spot that some of the intervals are 30° and some are 60°.  You could make `slices` const, though.

Comment: It's worth noting that your code attains a different result when the angle is `30`.

Comment: Could make, e.g. the entry for 180 an alias for the entry for 210.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 AFAICT from gcc.godbolt, the generated asm is the same for both cases but sure, I can make it const.

Comment: I literally thought I saw the Konami Code in place of the enum there for a second.

Comment: Not sure about C++, but in C# this wouldn't work for negative inputs because `angle % 360` returns a negative value when `angle` is negative.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: C99 and C++ have the same requirement as C#: that if `q = a/b` and `r = a%b` then `q * b + r` must equal `a`. Thus it is legal in C99 for a remainder to be negative. BorgLeader, you can fix the problem with `(((angle % 360) + 360) % 360) / 30`.

Comment: @ericlippert, you and your computational mathematics knowledge continue to impress.

Comment: This is very clever, but it's completely unreadable, and no more likely to be maintainable, so I disagree that it is a good solution to the perceived "ugliness" of the original. There's an element of personal taste, here, I guess, but I find the cleaned up branching versions by x4u and motoDrizzt vastly preferable.

Comment: @IMSoP I disagree about the maintainability. Let's say you only handle left/right/up/down right now. Now change it so you handle 8 directions like the answer does currently. Which solution requires more changes to the code, and has more potential to introduce a bug? I say the original approach in the question.

Comment: @milleniumbug It depends on *how* it changes. What if you want some of the sectors to be 22.5 degrees wide (one sixteenth of a circle)? Or some really small sectors, so the lookup table becomes 20 items long, most of them repeats? Maybe it's about how you visualise the problem: do you look at the sectors, or the boundaries between them? I find "draw a boundary at 30 degrees, then one at 60 degrees, then one at 120 degrees..." easier to follow than "divide into 30 degree segments, label segment 1 as RIGHT, segment 2 as UP_RIGHT, segment 3 as UP, segment 4 also as UP...".

Comment: The only thing I can fault with this is the use of `enum` instead of `enum class`.

Comment: I'd factor out the angle normalization into a separate function.

Comment: I've got to second the "cleverness" critique. Whilst the original if definitely ugly, it is at least clear in its intent for the future you that will have to read it.

Comment: @EricLippert: Let's assume `a = 3`, `b = 4`. Then `q = 3/4` and `r = 3`. If i do the math correct the result of `3/4 * 4 + 3` is `6` (Generally speaking: `let a < b`). Why does C99 and C++ handle this differently?

Comment: @anon: In C, C++ and C#, dividing an integer by an integer gives an integer, so q is zero, not 3/4.

Comment: @EricLippert: Talking about integers - got it, thank you!

Comment: @anon: Consider -3 and 4. We have only three sensible choices: (1) q is 0, and r is -3, (2) q is -1 and r is 1, or (3) q and r have values such that q * b + r != a. In case (2) we have that (-3)/4 != -(3/4), which is repugnant. Denying (3) seems completely wrong. So we are left with concluding that sometimes the remainder can be negative.

Comment: O(n) vs O(1) for if/switch-based answers.

Comment: @cyanbeam O(n) vs O(1) what?

Comment: Using a for loop is actually bad as it has O(n) running time as opposed to O(1) for a lookup table/hashtable method. For 8 iterations it might not look *that* bad but when scaled up to say 1 million iterations it's actually very bad.

Comment: @cyanbeam the for loop in main is just a "demo", `GetDirectionForAngle` is what I'm proposing as a replacement for the if/else cascade, they're both O(1)...

Comment: @EricLippert to solve the negative angle issue you can just add 360 and then perform the module operation ((angle + 360) % 360) / 30

Comment: @Borgleader actually it took me sometime, too, to understand that it had nothing to do with the answer and was just a demo. As much as the answer is obviously valid anyway, what about splitting that part of code in a separate code section?

Comment: @motoDrizzt I added a comment instead, I prefer to have one "MVCE" code section.

Comment: @Zucch Your solution doesn't handle angles that are less than -360. If you're fine with that, then ok. Otherwise you need to use Eric's solution.

Comment: O(n) is O(1) if n does not grow.

Comment: @Borgleader: Actually, an if/else cascade is O(n) not O(1), where n is the number of clauses.  More importantly for small n, this is branchless and compiles to a few fast instructions.  The lookup table could miss in cache, but if used repeatedly will stay hot.  (i.e. if this function is part of performance-critical loop, it will perform well even with a different angle every time, unlike an if/else chain.  If this function is rarely used, it might be slow, but then it doesn't have a big impact on overall performance.  It would help to make sure the table entries are 8bit, if `enum` is 32b...)

Comment: Hey, I did a [take](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664691/6626496) on this as well, I would like to know if it was a good approach to the problem, thanks =)

Answer (score 72):

You can use [`map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and store the upper-bound of each angle in a map.

Working example below:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <map>

enum Direction
{
    RIGHT,
    UP_RIGHT,
    UP,
    UP_LEFT,
    LEFT,
    DOWN_LEFT,
    DOWN,
    DOWN_RIGHT
};

using AngleDirMap = std::map<int, Direction>;

AngleDirMap map = {
    { 30, RIGHT },
    { 60, UP_RIGHT },
    { 120, UP },
    { 150, UP_LEFT },
    { 210, LEFT },
    { 240, DOWN_LEFT },
    { 300, DOWN },
    { 330, DOWN_RIGHT },
    { 360, RIGHT }
};

Direction direction(int angle)
{
    assert(angle >= 0 && angle <= 360);

    auto it = map.lower_bound(angle);
    return it->second;
}

int main()
{
    Direction d;

    d = direction(45);
    assert(d == UP_RIGHT);

    d = direction(30);
    assert(d == RIGHT);

    d = direction(360);
    assert(d == RIGHT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No division required. Good!

Comment: @O.Jones: Division by a compile-time constant is fairly cheap, just a multiply and some shifts.  I'd go with one of the `table[angle%360/30]` answers because it's cheap and branchless.  *Far* cheaper than a tree-search loop, if this compiles to asm that's similar to the source.  (`std::unordered_map` is usually a hash table, but `std::map` is typically a red-black binary tree. 
The accepted answer effectively uses `angle%360 / 30` as a perfect hash function for angles (after replicating a couple entries, and Bijay's answer even avoids that with an offset)).

Comment: You could use `lower_bound` on a sorted array. That would be a lot more efficient than a `map`.

Comment: @PeterCordes map lookup is easy to write and easy to maintain. If ranges change, updating hashing code might introduce bugs and if ranges become non-uniform, it may simply fall apart.

Unless that code is performance critical, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @OhJeez: They already are non-uniform, which is handled by having the same value in multiple buckets.  Just use a smaller divisor to get more buckets, unless that means using a very small divisor and having way too many buckets.  Also, if performance doesn't matter, then an if/else chain is not bad either, if simplified by factoring out `this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle()` with a tmp var, and removing the redundant compare from each of the OP's `if()` clauses (checking for something that would have already matched the preceding if()).  Or use @ wilx's sorted-array suggestion.

Comment: A linear search of a flat array (as @wilx suggested) would be more efficient for a small table like this.  If you understand what a `map` is, `map.lower_bound` looks like a very inefficient solution for such a small table (especially with the map not being `static const`, and even then IDK if most implementations would compile that into proper static elements.  Probably you'd still get a constructor/initializer that dynamically allocated space for each element, so they might not all be in the same cache line).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, even a bisect on such a small table will probably be slower than linear search. I wanted just to point out, that not always the solution that is performing fastest is the best. In real world applications usually reliability and ease of maintenance outweigh the best possible performance. On the other hand, the original if-chain even when prettified is still terrible. Code which is unnecessary repetitive, long and having multiple exit points. I would go with either the map, or just a `for` loop through lower-bound table.

Comment: @OhJeez: I wouldn't say terrible, but I agree putting the data in a table where it's easy to modify without touching the logic is a big improvement.  If you like the readability and understandability of the logic of the code in this answer, then use it, but with a sorted array of structs instead of a `map`.  You can use `std::lower_bound` with an overloaded `operator<`, or like you say just use a for loop.  To me, a tree search just screams "wrong algorithm for the problem", but my main interest is optimizing stuff.  Not being able to ignore perf slows me down when it doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 58):

Create an array, each element of which is associated with a block of 30 degrees:

```
Car::EDirection dirlist[] = { 
    Car::EDirection::RIGHT, 
    Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT, 
    Car::EDirection::UP, 
    Car::EDirection::UP, 
    Car::EDirection::UP_LEFT, 
    Car::EDirection::LEFT, 
    Car::EDirection::LEFT, 
    Car::EDirection::DOWN_LEFT,
    Car::EDirection::DOWN, 
    Car::EDirection::DOWN, 
    Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT, 
    Car::EDirection::RIGHT
};
```

Then you can index the array with the angle / 30:

```
this->_car.edir = dirlist[(this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() % 360) / 30];
```

No comparisons or branching required.

The result however is *slightly* off from the original.  Values on the borders, i.e. 30, 60, 120, etc. are placed in the next category.  For example, in the original code the valid values for `UP_RIGHT` are 31 to 60.  The above code assigns 30 to 59 to `UP_RIGHT`.

We can get around this by subtracting 1 from the angle:

```
this->_car.edir = dirlist[((this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() - 1) % 360) / 30];
```

This now gives us `RIGHT` for 30, `UP_RIGHT` for 60, etc.

In the case of 0, the expression becomes `(-1 % 360) / 30`.  This is valid because `-1 % 360 == -1` and `-1 / 30 == 0`, so we still get an index of 0.

Section 5.6 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) confirms this behavior:

> *4* The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the first
>   expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero
>   the behavior is undefined. For integral operands the `/` operator
>   yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. if
>   the quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result,
>   `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a`.

EDIT:

There were many questions raised regarding the readability and maintainability of a construct like this.  The answer given by motoDrizzt is a good example of simplifying the original construct that is more maintainable and isn't quite as "ugly".

Expanding on his answer, here's another example making use of the ternary operator.  Since each case in the original post is assigning to the same variable, using this operator can help increase readability further.

```
int angle = ((this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() % 360) + 360) % 360;

this->_car.edir = (angle <= 30)  ?  Car::EDirection::RIGHT :
                  (angle <= 60)  ?  Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT :
                  (angle <= 120) ?  Car::EDirection::UP :
                  (angle <= 150) ?  Car::EDirection::UP_LEFT :
                  (angle <= 210) ?  Car::EDirection::LEFT : 
                  (angle <= 240) ?  Car::EDirection::DOWN_LEFT :
                  (angle <= 300) ?  Car::EDirection::DOWN:  
                  (angle <= 330) ?  Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT :
                                    Car::EDirection::RIGHT;
```

Answer (score 49):

That code is not ugly, it's simple, practical, readable and easy to understand. It will be isolated in it's own method, so nobody will have to deal with it in everyday life. And just in case someone has to check it -maybe because he is debugging your application for a problem somewhere else- it's so easy it will take him two seconds to understand the code and what it does.

If I was doing such a debug I'd be happy to not have to spend five minutes trying to understand what your function does. In this regards, all other functions fail completely, as they change a simple, forget-about-it, bugs free routine, in a complicated mess that people when debugging will be forced to deeply analyse and test. As a project manager myself I'd strongly get upset by a developer taking a simple task and instead of implementing it into a simple, harmless way, wastes time to implement it into an over complicate way. Just think all the time you wasted thinking about it, then coming to SO asking, and all for just the sake of worsening maintenance and readability of the thing.

That said, there is a common mistake in your code that make it quite less readable, and a couple improvements you can do quite easily:

```
int angle = this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle();

if (angle <= 30 || angle >= 330)
  return Car::EDirection::RIGHT;
else if (angle <= 60)
  return Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT;
else if (angle <= 120)
  return Car::EDirection::UP;
else if (angle <= 150)
  return Car::EDirection::UP_LEFT;
else if (angle <= 210)
  return Car::EDirection::LEFT;
else if (angle <= 240)
  return Car::EDirection::DOWN_LEFT;
else if (angle <= 300)
  return Car::EDirection::DOWN;
else if (angle <= 330)
  return Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT;
```

Put this into a method, assign the returned value to the object, collapse the method, and forget about it for the rest of eternity.

P.S. there is another bug over the 330 threshold, but I don't know how you want to treat it, so I didn't fix it at all.

---

**Later update**

As per comment, you can even get rid of the else if at all:

```
int angle = this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle();

if (angle <= 30 || angle >= 330)
  return Car::EDirection::RIGHT;

if (angle <= 60)
  return Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT;

if (angle <= 120)
  return Car::EDirection::UP;

if (angle <= 150)
  return Car::EDirection::UP_LEFT;

if (angle <= 210)
  return Car::EDirection::LEFT;

if (angle <= 240)
  return Car::EDirection::DOWN_LEFT;

if (angle <= 300)
  return Car::EDirection::DOWN;

if (angle <= 330)
  return Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT;
```

I didn't do it 'cause I feel that a certain point it becomes just a matter of own preferences, and the scope of my answer was (and is) to give a different perspective to your concern about "ugliness of code". Anyway, as I said, someone pointed it out in the comments and I think it makes sense to show it.

Comment: What the hell was that supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 39):

In pseudocode:

```
angle = (angle + 30) %360; // Offset by 30.
```

So, we have `0-60`, `60-90`, `90-150`,... as the categories. 
In each quadrant with 90 degrees, one part has 60, one part has 30. So, now:

```
i = angle / 90; // Figure out the quadrant. Could be 0, 1, 2, 3 

j = (angle - 90 * i) >= 60? 1: 0; // In the quardrant is it perfect (eg: RIGHT) or imperfect (eg: UP_RIGHT)?

index = i * 2 + j;
```

Use the index in an array containing the enums in the appropriate order.

Comment: This is good,probably the best answer here.  Chances are that if the original questioner looked at his use of the enum later he'd find that he has a case where it's just being converted back into a number!  Eliminating the enum completely and just sticking with a direction integer probably makes sense with other places in his code and this answer gets you directly there.

Answer (score 18):

```
switch (this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle() / 30) // integer division
{
    case 0:
    case 11: this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::RIGHT; break;
    case 1: this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT; break;
    ...
    case 10: this->_car.edir = Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT; break;
}
```

Comment: angle = this->_car.getAbsoluteAngle(); sector = (angle%360)/30; Result is 12 sectors. Then index into array, or use switch/case as above - which compiler transforms into jump table anyway.

Comment: Switch not really better than if/else chains.

Comment: @BillK: It might be, if the compiler turns it into a table lookup for you.  That's more likely than with an if/else chain.  But since it's easy and doesn't require any architecture-specific tricks, it's probably best to write the table-lookup in the source code.

Comment: Generally performance shouldn't be a concern--it's readability and maintainability--every switch & if/else chain usually means a bunch of messy copy and paste code that has to be updated in multiple places whenever you add a new item.  Best to avoid both and try dispatch tables, calculations or just load data from a file and treat it as data if you can.

Comment: PeterCordes the compiler is likely to generate identical code for the LUT  as for the switch. @BillK you can extract the switch into a 0..12 -> Car::EDirection function, which would have equivalent repetition to a LUT

Comment: I like this. It's readable *and* most likely will be converted into a lookup table by the compiler. Borgleader's answer forces a loop which doesn't scale up for these types of problems.

Comment: @Caleth it depends on how it's used.  If you can use a 1..12 value and skip the enum altogether you are much better off than going through the whole switch/enum mess.  For instance, if the point of the whole process is to pick one of 12 pictures to use then the enum is completely unhelpful and actually distracts from writing good code.  That is why enums and if/elses should be your last choice for things like this.  The efficiency of the code generated by the compiler is generally not important compared to having more readable maintainable code.

Answer (score 16):

Ignoring your first `if` which is a bit of a special case, the remaining ones all follow the exact same pattern: a min, max and direction; pseudo-code:

```
if (angle > min && angle <= max)
  _car.edir = direction;
```

Making this real C++ might look like:

```
enum class EDirection {  NONE,
   RIGHT, UP_RIGHT, UP, UP_LEFT, LEFT, DOWN_LEFT, DOWN, DOWN_RIGHT };

struct AngleRange
{
    int min, max;
    EDirection direction;
};
```

Now, rather than writing a bunch of `if`s, just loop over your various possibilies:

```
EDirection direction_from_angle(int angle, const std::vector<AngleRange>& angleRanges)
{
    for (auto&& angleRange : angleRanges)
    {
        if ((angle > angleRange.min) && (angle <= angleRange.max))
            return angleRange.direction;
    }

    return EDirection::NONE;
}
```

(`throw`ing an exception rather than `return`ing `NONE` is another option).

Which you would then call:

```
_car.edir = direction_from_angle(_car.getAbsoluteAngle(), {
    {30, 60, EDirection::UP_RIGHT},
    {60, 120, EDirection::UP},
    // ... etc.
});
```

This technique is known as [data-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming).  Besides getting rid of a bunch of `if`s, it would allow you to use easily add more directions (e.g., NNW) or reduce the number (left, right, up, down) without re-working other code.

---

(Handling your first special case is left as "an exercise for the reader." :-) )

Comment: Technically you could eliminate min given that all the angle ranges match up, which would reduce the condition to `if(angle <= angleRange.max)` but +1 for using C++11 features like `enum class`.

Answer (score 12):

Although the proposed variants based on a lookup table for `angle / 30` are probably preferable, here is an alternative that uses a hard coded binary search to minimize the number of comparisons.

```
static Car::EDirection directionFromAngle( int angle )
{
    if( angle <= 210 )
    {
        if( angle > 120 )
            return angle > 150 ? Car::EDirection::LEFT
                               : Car::EDirection::UP_LEFT;
        if( angle > 30 )
            return angle > 60 ? Car::EDirection::UP
                              : Car::EDirection::UP_RIGHT;
    }
    else // > 210
    {
        if( angle <= 300 )
            return angle > 240 ? Car::EDirection::DOWN
                               : Car::EDirection::DOWN_LEFT;
        if( angle <= 330 )
            return Car::EDirection::DOWN_RIGHT;
    }
    return Car::EDirection::RIGHT; // <= 30 || > 330
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid duplication you can express this as a mathematical formula.

First of all, assume that we are using @Geek's Enum

```
Enum EDirection { RIGHT =0, UP_RIGHT, UP, UP_LEFT, LEFT, DOWN_LEFT,DOWN, DOWN_RIGHT}
```

Now we can compute the enum using integer mathematics (with out the need for arrays).

```
EDirection angle2dir(int angle) {
    int d = ( ((angle%360)+360)%360-1)/30;
    d-=d/3; //some directions cover a 60 degree arc
    d%=8;
    //printf ("assert(angle2dir(%3d)==%-10s);\n",angle,dir2str[d]);
    return (EDirection) d;
}
```

As @motoDrizzt points out, concise code isn't necessarily readable code. It does have the small advantage that expressing it as maths makes it explicit that some directions cover a wider arc. If you want to go this direction you can add some asserts to help understand the code.

```
assert(angle2dir(  0)==RIGHT     ); assert(angle2dir( 30)==RIGHT     );
assert(angle2dir( 31)==UP_RIGHT  ); assert(angle2dir( 60)==UP_RIGHT  );
assert(angle2dir( 61)==UP        ); assert(angle2dir(120)==UP        );
assert(angle2dir(121)==UP_LEFT   ); assert(angle2dir(150)==UP_LEFT   );
assert(angle2dir(151)==LEFT      ); assert(angle2dir(210)==LEFT      );
assert(angle2dir(211)==DOWN_LEFT ); assert(angle2dir(240)==DOWN_LEFT );
assert(angle2dir(241)==DOWN      ); assert(angle2dir(300)==DOWN      );
assert(angle2dir(301)==DOWN_RIGHT); assert(angle2dir(330)==DOWN_RIGHT);
assert(angle2dir(331)==RIGHT     ); assert(angle2dir(360)==RIGHT     );
```

Having added the asserts you have added duplication, but duplication in asserts isn't so bad. If you have an inconsistent assert you will find out soon enough. Asserts can be compiled out of release version so as not to bloat the executable you distribute. Nevertheless, this approach is probably most applicable if you want to optimize the code rather than just make it less ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Late to the party, but We could use enum flags and range checks to do something neat.

```
enum EDirection {
    RIGHT =  0x01,
    LEFT  =  0x02,
    UP    =  0x04,
    DOWN  =  0x08,
    DOWN_RIGHT = DOWN | RIGHT,
    DOWN_LEFT = DOWN | LEFT,
    UP_RIGHT = UP | RIGHT,
    UP_LEFT = UP | LEFT,

    // just so we be clear, these won't have much use though
    IMPOSSIBLE_H = RIGHT | LEFT, 
    IMPOSSIBLE_V = UP | DOWN
};
```

the checking(pseudo-code), assuming angle is absolue (between 0 and 360):

```
int up    = (angle >   30 && angle <  150) * EDirection.UP;
int down  = (angle >  210 && angle <  330) * EDirection.DOWN;
int right = (angle <=  60 || angle >= 330) * EDirection.Right;
int left  = (angle >= 120 && angle <= 240) * EDirection.LEFT;

EDirection direction = (Direction)(up | down | right | left);

switch(direction){
    case RIGHT:
         // do right
         break;
    case UP_RIGHT:
         // be honest
         break;
    case UP:
         // whats up
         break;
    case UP_LEFT:
         // do you even left
         break;
    case LEFT:
         // 5 done 3 to go
         break;
    case DOWN_LEFT:
         // your're driving me to a corner here
         break;
    case DOWN:
         // :(
         break;
    case DOWN_RIGHT:
         // completion
         break;

    // hey, we mustn't let these slide
    case IMPOSSIBLE_H:
    case IMPOSSIBLE_V:
        // treat your impossible case here!
        break;
}
```